# Unable to install LightTable for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, leiningen, lighttable

I got Ubuntu 14.04 and realy whant to try LightTable. But cant even install it. All troubles I got are about leiningen.

I reproduced this steps just like [manual said](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable) without any errors:

```
First install or update leiningen.

Download the lein script. For Windows, download lein.bat.
Place it on your $PATH where your shell can find it (eg. ~/bin).
Set it to be an executable (chmod a+x ~/bin/lein).
Run the Lein script (eg. "./lein" or "sh lein") without quotes.
```

After that, I have tried next steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable.git
cd LightTable
bash linux_deps.sh
```

but the all I got is:

```
Please install leiningen before running this script.
```

If I run:

```
lein version
```

I receive:

```
bash: /usr/bin/lein: No such file or directory
```

The result of ./lein is:

```
Leiningen is a tool for working with Clojure projects.

Several tasks are available:
check               Check syntax and warn on reflection.
classpath           Write the classpath of the current project to output-file.
clean               Remove all files from paths in project's clean-targets.
compile             Compile Clojure source into .class files.
deploy              Deploy jar and pom to remote repository.
deps                Show details about dependencies.
do                  Higher-order task to perform other tasks in succession.
help                Display a list of tasks or help for a given task or subtask.
install             Install current project to the local repository.
jar                 Package up all the project's files into a jar file.
javac               Compile Java source files.
new                 Generate scaffolding for a new project based on a template.
plugin              DEPRECATED. Please use the :user profile instead.
pom                 Write a pom.xml file to disk for Maven interoperability.
repl                Start a repl session either with the current project or standalone.
retest              Run only the test namespaces which failed last time around.
run                 Run the project's -main function.
search              Search remote maven repositories for matching jars.
show-profiles       List all available profiles or display one if given an argument.
test                Run the project's tests.
trampoline          Run a task without nesting the project's JVM inside Leiningen's.
uberjar             Package up the project files and all dependencies into a jar file.
update-in           Perform arbitrary transformations on your project map.
upgrade             Upgrade Leiningen to specified version or latest stable.
version             Print version for Leiningen and the current JVM.
with-profile        Apply the given task with the profile(s) specified.

Run `lein help $TASK` for details.

Global Options:
  -o             Run a task offline.
  -U             Run a task after forcing update of snapshots.
  -h, --help     Print this help.
  -v, --version  Print Leiningen's version.

See also: readme, faq, tutorial, news, sample, profiles, deploying, gpg, mixed-source, templates, and copying.
```

What I have done wrong? What else should I do to became a LightTable user?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Java installed?  It's required for Leiningen, but not mentioned in the install directions on their [main page](http://leiningen.org/).  They only mention it in their installation instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/tree/stable).  You'll also need to have cURL installed, but that's for LightTable itself, not Leiningen.

I was just able to install and run LightBox on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing OpenJDK (Java 7 version), Leiningen, Git, and cURL, so hopefully you're just missing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well this part:

```
bash: /usr/bin/lein: No such file or directory
```

Is because it cannot find the command, is it located in that directory?  What did you add to the $PATH in your profile?  I am guessing but I think you need to correctly add it to your $PATH env.  If you run

```
env
```

What does that display?

Answer (score 0):

To remove lighttable from ubuntu 32bit or 64bit.do,

```
sudo rm -r /opt/LightTable /usr/bin/lighttable
```